# What is the difference between IRandomAccessStream and RandomAccessStream?

Tags: c#

I have used the following code to save a recently taken image:

```
private async void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
{    
   StorageFile photo = 
      await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("Image.jpg");    

  BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();    
  using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))  
  {  
      bmp.SetSource(stream);  
  }  
  img.Source = bmp;  
}
```

What is the use of `IRandomAccessStream` and what will be the difference on replacing it with `RandomAccessStream`?

Comment: -1 You should probably look it up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream. One is an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx) and the other is a [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx) that implements the interface.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Correction: the other one is a [class that *doesn't* implement the interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.randomaccessstream.aspx) :-) I was really surprised to find that the two are unrelated.

Comment: One is an interface, and one is a concrete class that presumably implements it. Leave you code as it is, if GetFileAsync was to return an other class, that also implemented the interface, your code would break.

Comment: @JohnSaunders , it doesn't? Wow Ms coder boys need to start peer reviewing...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: wow! The naming is so bad there that I'd almost consider it to be a bug.

Comment: Just like IEnumerable and Enumerable.

Answer (score 4):

It's confusing because they have similar names. They are related but not in the way one would assume.

[RandomAccessStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.randomaccessstream.aspx) is a static helper class.

[IRandomAccessStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream.aspx) is an interface that all concreete random access streams implement, such as [FileRandomAccessStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.filerandomaccessstream.aspx) and [InMemoryRandomAccessStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.aspx).

This means that they are not interchangeable. You use `RandomAccessStream` to perform operations, namely copying data between two instances of other streams.

`photo.OpenAsync` will return a `FileRandomAccessStream` but unless you need the specific functionality that the concrete class provides, you should usually stick to programming against the interface, `IRandomAccessStream`.